# How to specify gcm.cache location using g++ & CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am currently working on a project which requires C++20 (g++ v11) features and CMake. The project tree is similar to the following one:

```
- Top level
  - src
     - IO
       - IO.cpp
       - CMakeLists.txt
  - main.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
```

CMake compiles IO module without any problem but It generates gcm.cache folder in a following way:

```
- build
   - Some other CMake files and folders
   - bin
   - lib 
   - src
     - IO
       - gcm.cache
          - IO.gcm
```

Therefore, g++ can not find gcm.cache folder and gives me this error:

```
IO: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
IO: note: compiled module file is 'gcm.cache/IO.gcm'
IO: note: imports must be built before being imported
IO: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
```

I would be grateful if anyone tell me that there is a way to specify gcm.cache locations using CMake or force CMake to search gcm files recursively or tell it to create a top level gcm.cache and store everything inside of it. I can not find any answer on anywhere since C++20 documentations are terrible. Thanks in advance...

Comment: NOTE: I am using modules-ts at compilation step.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the exact same issue, and without actually discovering a solution have found a workaround. Complete code found [here](https://github.com/alexpanter/modules_testing/tree/master/gcc-testing/test_07_gameengine).

In short, I create a symbolic link such that subprojects are all using the gcm.cache/ directory located in the root directory of the project. Create a symlink like so:

```
ln -fs ../gcm.cache gcm.cache
```

This is the directory tree of the project:

```
.
├── engine
│   ├── core
│   │   └── types.cpp
│   ├── engine.cpp
│   ├── gcm.cache -> ../gcm.cache
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── memory
├── gcm.cache
├── init.sh
├── Makefile
└── testgame
    ├── gamelib.cpp
    ├── gcm.cache -> ../gcm.cache
    ├── Makefile
    └── test.cpp
```

So when gcc builds the `engine` and `testgame` projects it actually uses the gcm.cache/ from the root directory. Until something better comes along this is my go-to method.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine (Ubuntu 22.04 running g++ with gcc version 11.4.0) I was able to apply the answer from [How to modify gcm.cache path when using gcc-11 to build c++20 modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69549286/how-to-modify-gcm-cache-path-when-using-gcc-11-to-build-c20-modules), which uses a compiler flag to specify where g++ searches for and builds module files. In short, when building any files that create or use CMI files (the ones with a .gcm suffix), add this entire flag: `'-fmodule-mapper=|@g++-mapper-server -r'<INSERT YOUR DESIRED PATH HERE>`. As of writing, it doesn't look like you need to create the destination folder before compiling.

I've created an example at https://github.com/michigan-musicer/modules-demo. It looks like this:

test.cpp

```cpp
export module TuckTuck;

import <iostream>;

namespace TuckTuck 
{
    int internal_function() 
    {
        std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
        return 5;
    }

    export int external_function()
    {
        return internal_function();
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
import TuckTuck;
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << TuckTuck::external_function() << std::endl;
}
```

Makefile

```
LIB_PATH := ./lib
GCM_PATH := $(LIB_PATH)/gcm.cache
# mapper process lets us specify where to build and fetch GCM libs, based on magic from this SO post
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69549286/how-to-modify-gcm-cache-path-when-using-gcc-11-to-build-c20-modules
MAPPER := '-fmodule-mapper=|@g++-mapper-server -r'$(GCM_PATH)
FLAGS := g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts

STD_INCLUDES := iostream

all: std_includes test main

main:
    $(FLAGS) $(MAPPER) main.cpp -o main -Xlinker $(LIB_PATH)/test.so 

test: 
    $(FLAGS) $(MAPPER) -fPIC -c test.cpp -o test.o
    $(FLAGS) $(MAPPER) -shared test.o -o $(LIB_PATH)/test.so
    rm test.o

std_includes:
    $(FLAGS) $(MAPPER) -xc++-system-header $(STD_INCLUDES)
```

After running `make` I get a project layout that looks like this:

```
- lib
  - gcm.cache
     - usr / include / c++ / 11
        - iostream.gcm
     - TuckTuck.gcm
  - test.so
- main
- (original source files)
```

More on modules in g++ at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Modules.html and more on the module mapper specifically at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Module-Mapper.html.