# How to modify gcm.cache path when using gcc-11 to build c++20 modules?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++-modules, xmake

I am trying to let [xmake](https://github.com/xmake-io/xmake) support gcc-11 to build c++20 modules, but I have some problems.

gcc-11 will generate the `gcm.cache` directory in the current directory by default. How can I modify this default path to the specified other directory?

I know that clang has a `-fmodules-cache-path=` option to modify the cache path of modules, but I did not find a similar option for gcc.

Does anyone know? thanks

Comment: I have not been able to find it. There is nothing in the man-page for g++, neither is it mentioned in their modules documentation. So I assume (at least for the moment) that it is not possible. Hopefully, they will add it one day.

Comment: Read this page:

   gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Module-Mapper.html

You'd have to create your own "module-mapper" to make this work. I have my own custom build environment, so I'm thinking of a super simple program that reads all of your source, and creates the module-map file, and supplies it as an environment variable.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me `gcc-11` on ubuntu 22.04 (Makefile fragment):

```
MAPPER_DIR := /path/to/obj/dir

CXXFLAGS += -fmodules-ts '-fmodule-mapper=|@g++-mapper-server -r'$(MAPPER_DIR)
```

The caveat I ran into is that `g++-mapper-server` won't create the root directory, so make sure its created first.  You'll still have to work out dependencies so that the gcm is created/updated before the importing code is compiled.

---

The explanation is `|` invokes a mapper process via pipe, `@` resolves the process name from the gcc tools directory (cf [gcc manual](https://%20https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Module-Mapper.html)).  The `-r` option sets the root directory.  Take care protecting the spaces and the `|` from `make` and shell.

The default mapper server takes arguments - you can tweak and play with it - here's the options on my version:

```
$ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/g++-mapper-server --help
Usage: g++-mapper-server [OPTION...] [CONNECTION] [MAPPINGS...] 

C++ Module Mapper.

  -a, --accept     Netmask to accept from
  -f, --fallback   Use fallback for missing mappings
  -h, --help       Print this help, then exit
  -n, --noisy      Print progress messages
  -1, --one        One connection and then exit
  -r, --root DIR   Root compiled module directory
  -s, --sequential Process connections sequentially
  -v, --version    Print version number, then exit
Send SIGTERM(15) to terminate

For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs>.
```

Comment: Thanks, I have supported it using module mapper. https://github.com/xmake-io/xmake/blob/e893ca8f313b7f267e0d9189fdea457e65405ba1/xmake/rules/c%2B%2B/modules/modules_support/gcc.lua#L40-L56